# TootTip issue with d3.js chart

Tags: d3.js

I want to add toottip to my d3 chart but i am not able to do so..Any help would be appreciated..

Program code:

```
    var w = 300;
    var h = 250;
    var r = h / 2;
    var color = d3.scale.category20c();
    var data = [{ "label": "1", "value": 64 },
                      { "label": "2", "value": 1 },
                      { "label": "3", "value": 19 },
                      { "label": "4", "value": 17 },
                      { "label": "5", "value": 1 }];
    var tip = d3.tip()
        .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
        .offset([-10, 0])
        .html(function (d) {
            return "<strong>Frequency:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.label + "</span>";
        });
    var vis = d3.select('#chart').append("svg:svg").data([data]).attr("width", w).attr("height", h).append("svg:g").attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")");
    var pie = d3.layout.pie().value(function (d) { return d.value; });          
    var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(r);       
    var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice").data(pie).enter().append("svg:g").attr("class", "slice").on('mouseover', tip.show)
  .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
    arcs.append("svg:path")
        .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
            return color(i);
        })
        .attr("d", function (d) {

            console.log(arc(d));
            return arc(d);
        });


    arcs.append("svg:text").attr("transform", function (d) {
        d.innerRadius = 0;
        d.outerRadius = r;
        return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
    }).attr("text-anchor", "middle").text(function (d, i) {
        return data[i].label;
    }
            );
```

Comment: try `.on('mouseover', function () { tip.show() }).on('mouseout', function() { tip.hide()});`. Also any error in console ?

Comment: yes it is showing Cannot read property 'label' of undefined error

Comment: is that for `return "<strong>Frequency:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.label + "</span>";` this line? can you post a fiddle of it ?

Comment: is that solved your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the tip on svg. you are missing following code.

```
vis.call(tip);
```

check documentation https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip

Comment: Hey!!Thank u for your support but i used other code for creating d3 chart..It is working fine